# how to add column name present in the list object into table

Tags: python, mysql

how to do like this

```
cursor.execute("create table" + config.table + config.cols)
```

all the config names are in different files and cols is a list object like this

```
cols = [
  "name varchar(50)",
  "address varchar(50)",
  "etc "
```

i have a error like this

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
```

how to concatenate str with the list objects...
Please help!!

Comment: Have you bothered trying to convert the list into a string?

Comment: [`str.join()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you want to combine a list (or array) with a string, you need to use join(). 
Assuming config.table is a string, and config.cols is an array/list, you might want something like:

```
cursor.execute("create table " + config.table + " (" + ", ".join(config.cols) + ")")
```

This combines all the individual cols, by putting commas between them (but not before the first or after the last). I also added a () around the field definition, and a space between the word table, and the table name.

If it still doesn't work, try printing the string out, instead of executing it, to make sure it is valid SQL.

Comment: use mydict.items() to convert it a list of (key,value) tuples. Use list comprehension to convert the tuples to a string. then use join as above. `mycolstojoin=["%s %s" % (field[0],field[1]) for field in mydict.items()]` (assuming a `mydict=={"name":"varchar(50)"...}` )